# Get all files from directory instead of just single file in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I am trying to resize images using the Tinify Node JS API. I would like to resize a directory of files instead of just a single file. This is is the code for resizing one file:

```
const source = tinify.fromFile("example.jpg");
const resized = source.resize({
  method: "cover",
  width: 720,
  height: 225
});
resized.toFile("example-small.jpg");
```

Similarly I'd like to do the same for converting all files in a directory to `.webp`:

```
const source = tinify.fromFile("example.jpg");
const converted = source.convert({type:["image/webp","image/png"]});
const extension = converted.result().extension();
extension.then(ext => {
  converted.toFile("example." + ext);
})
```

My knowledge of NodeJS is somewhat limited, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read All Files from the Source Directory: Utilize the fs module in Node.js to enumerate all files within the specified source directory.

Resize Each Image: Employ the Tinify API to resize each image according to the predefined dimensions, similar to the previously described method.

Save the Resized Images: Store the resized images in the designated destination directory, retaining their original file names for easy identification and consistency.

This is demo code.

Save as `converts.js` file name

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const tinify = require("tinify");
const sharp = require("sharp");

tinify.key = "[ YOUR API KEY ]"; // Replace with your actual API key

const sourceDir = "image/png";
const destDir = "image/webp";
async function resizeAndConvertImages() {
    try {
        const files = fs.readdirSync(sourceDir);

        for (const file of files) {
            const ext = path.extname(file).toLowerCase();
            if (ext === '.png' || ext === '.jpg' || ext === '.jpeg') {
                const sourcePath = path.join(sourceDir, file);

                // Ensure the destination path has a .webp extension
                const destFileName = path.basename(file, ext) + '.webp';
                const destPath = path.join(destDir, destFileName);

                // Resize the image using Tinify
                const resizedBuffer = await tinify.fromFile(sourcePath).resize({
                    method: "cover",
                    width: 720,
                    height: 225
                }).toBuffer();

                // Convert the image to WebP format using Sharp
                await sharp(resizedBuffer)
                    .toFormat('webp')
                    .toFile(destPath);
                console.log(`${file} has been resized and converted to WebP, saved as ${destPath}`);
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error during processing:", error);
    }
}

resizeAndConvertImages();
```

##### Get API Key

From your  **tinify** Dashboard

```
https://tinify.com/dashboard/api
```

[image]

##### Input directory

It mixed JPG and PNG images
[image]

[image]

##### Install Dependency

Running on node "v18.19.0"

```
npm install tinify sharp
```

##### Run it

```bash
node converts.js
```

[image]

##### Result

[image]

Some images may be cropped or clipped due to the resizing method used by Tinify's API.

[image]

##### Checking `.webp` file confirm

In [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) 2.10.32 (revision 1)

[image]

Comment: I've been working with this and it doesn't convert the images, it's just changing the extension from `.jpg` to `.webp`.

Comment: Yes, current logic just clipped and extension change from .jpg to .webp or .png to .webp
Do you want to real convert too. I will try it after return home.

Comment: @Stenchaholic, I updated my code with adding "sharp" library and confirmed real .webp image format by GIMP. let me know you can reproduce it.